# Tensorflow error using tf.image.random : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

**Intro**

I am using a modified version of the Tensorflow tutorial "Deep MNIST for experts" with the Python API for a medical images classification project using convolutionnal networks.

I want to artificially increase the size of my training set by applying random modifications on the images of my training set.

**Problem**

When I run the line :

```
flipped_images = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(images)
```

I get de following error :

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

My Tensor "images" is an ndarray `(shape=[batch, im_size, im_size, channels])` of "batch" ndarrays `(shape=[im_size, im_size, channels])`.

Just to check if my input data was packed in the right shape and type, I have tried to apply this simple function in the (not modified) tutorial "Tensorflow Mechanics 101" and I get the same error.

Finally, I still get the same error trying to use the following functions :

- `tf.image.random_flip_up_down()`
- `tf.image.random_brightness()`
- `tf.image.random_contrast()`

**Questions**

As input data is usually carried in Tensorflow as ndarrays, I would like to know :

1. Is it a bug of Tensorflow Python API or is it my "fault" because
   of the type/shape of my input data?
2. How could I get it to work and be able to apply    `tf.image.random_flip_left_right` to my training set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This seems like an inconsistency in the TensorFlow API, since almost all other op functions accept NumPy arrays wherever a `tf.Tensor` is expected. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1409) to track the fix.

Fortunately, there is a simple workaround, using [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#convert_to_tensor). Replace your code with the following:

```
flipped_images = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(tf.convert_to_tensor(images))
```