# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, google-colaboratory, numpy-ndarray

As I'm running `beginner.ipynb` from [google's intro to tensorflow](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/quickstart/beginner.ipynb) locally, the execution breaks at

```
predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
```

with the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-6d3178b039b4> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
      2 # print( type( predictions ) )
      3 # predictions = tf.convert_to_tensor( model(x_train[:1]) )
      4 predictions
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    590       else:
    591         # Eager execution on data tensors.
--> 592         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    593         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    594         return outputs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    228   def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
    229     if self._is_graph_network:
--> 230       return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    231 
    232     outputs, _ = self._call_and_compute_mask(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    813     outputs, _ = self._run_internal_graph(inputs,
    814                                           training=training,
--> 815                                           mask=masks)
    816     return outputs
    817 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
   1000                   output_tensors = layer(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
   1001                 else:
-> 1002                   output_tensors = layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
   1003                 if hasattr(layer, 'compute_mask'):
   1004                   output_masks = layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py in call(self, inputs)
    553                  array_ops.shape(inputs)[0], -1))
    554     if not context.executing_eagerly():
--> 555       outputs.set_shape(self.compute_output_shape(inputs.get_shape()))
    556     return outputs
    557 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824798/tensorflow-error-using-tf-image-random-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute) but was unable to apply the suggested fix.

How should I make the code work? Why is the same code running fine on collab but fails on my local machine?

Comment: update your full code and error trace if possible

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, done!

Comment: That error message pretty clearly shows you're *not* running `predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()`. You've made a bunch of changes, and we can't see the full extent.

Comment: @user2357112-supports-Monica, sorry, forgot to update. I was just trying various changes. But it was the original code which did not work.

Comment: I found this post because I have exactly the same problem. As @AzyCrw4282 said, it seems that "update your full code" is the solution. But, as a really beginner, I don't understand the meaning: what does it mean to update the full code? Could you please explain what do I have to do? What kind of manipulation? Sorry if it's a dummy question...

Comment: Apparently the problem was using the wrong version of tensorflow. Make sure you installed tensorflow2.

Comment: @Andrew sorry for the confusion. The initial post of the question did not contain the full code and error trace so I wrote this `"update your full code"`  to ask the OP to update that. That's not the solution. To solve it use Tensorflow2.x- see answer i post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as mentioned by the OP is to to use `tensorflow2`. 
Though it wasn't possible to get to the root cause of this problem it seems like it may be stemming from unsupported functionality in `tensorflow1.x`.

See [here for the changes](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/tensorflow-1-x-vs-2-x-summary-of-changes) of **1.x vs 2.x**