# TensorFlow official documentation tutorial error ''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray, attributeerror

I was trying to run the exact code on the TensorFlow tutorial [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/quickstart/beginner.ipynb#scrollTo=04QgGZc9bF5D).

When I get to line:

```
predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
```

I get the error:

`'numpy.ndarray'` object has no attribute `'get_shape'`

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824798/tensorflow-error-using-tf-image-random-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute) that someone had a similar issue, so I changed the line to:

```
predictions = model(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train[:1])).numpy()
```

And I get the error:

Input `'b'` of `'MatMul'` Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument `'a'`

Could someone tell me the correct code that should be in the tutorial? Or is it an issue on my side?

One thing that is strange is it runs if I run the code in the colab notebook provided, but if I download the jupyter notebook to run locally, that's when I get the error. So I'm wondering if I have a different/wrong version of TensorFlow?

My packages:

```
tensorflow                1.13.1            
tensorflow-base           1.13.1            
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                       
python                    3.7.6
```

Comment: did you install `numpy` package?

Comment: I did, numpy (version 1.15.4) and  numpy-base (version 1.15.4)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are referencing is in Tensorflow 2.x (where Eager mode is by default). In Eager mode you can access a tensor with `.numpy()` method to get numpy value of the tensor.

In your local, you have TensorFlow 1.13.1 which runs the model in graph mode. You can access the numpy value of the `graph tensor` (not eager tensor) by running a session and evaluating the tensor. [Here](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/) is one tutorial on TF1.x with mnist data. Overall, in TF1.x, you need to create a graph, create placeholders, then run a Session, feed the data to placeholders, and train the model, then predict.

Other alternative is to install Tensorflow 2.x by running "pip3 install tensorflow==2.1`. After installing, you can run the example without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your first question is that your `model()` accept `tensor` type parameters not `numpy`. And `model(x)`  called `x.get_shape()`.
In `x.get_shape()`, `x` must be `tensor`. So, your need transform `numpy` to `tensor`.  You can use `tf.convert_to_tensor(x)` or `tf.constant(x)`

---

The second error message is `Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'a'`. The message means that in `a x b` `a` type is float64 and `b` type is float32. They are different type variables, so they can't be multiplied. You can try use `tf.cast(a,tf.float32)` to change the type of `a` or change `b`. But in your code, you should use `x_train[:1].dtype` to check the type of `x_train[:1]`. If it is float32 you can try use `x_train[:1].astype(np.float64)` to transform it or vice versa. Or use `tf.constant(x_train[:1],dtype=tf.float64)`